# php mail headers for outlook - the email arrives empty to outlook, and great to gmail to yahoo

Tags: php, email, header, outlook-2003

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

the $header is:

```
From: from-me@mymail123.com
Reply-To: from-me@mymail123.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.5
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

I built `$header` with those line and I changed the order in every way, putting the Mime in the beginning, at the end, moving the from and reply around adding and deleting the X-mailer line. The results are the same. Gmail and yahoo are fine and the email is an empty attachment when set to outlook 2003.

Any thoughts?

sdfor

Comment: You'd be better off using something like PEAR to send HTML emails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks for the thoughts. I tried phpMailer and got stuck on a "Could not instantiate mail function" error. I posted a question about that too.

But I figured out the problem. Outlook requires a doctype and that the HTML be correct. gmail will take almost anything. \

The following works!

//the message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>HTML EMAIL</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

//the headers

```
$headers = "From: $from\n"
$headers .= "Reply-To: $replyto\n"
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
```

// the mail call

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Personnally, i prefer using [phpmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/), available on sourceforge. It offers a much more robust mailing solution.  I use it to send our email newsletter. Very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  to the end of 'From: ...'.  This email should be an actual email address on the server.   Try checking your spam folder with what you have.